Why does React re renders the component twice with same static value, after that it does not?
export default function Quiz() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(0);
  console.log("input::::::::::>>", input);

  function clickAnswerHandler() {
    console.log("hitting this:::::");
    setInput(1);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p> This is the currently active Question </p>

      <button onClick={() => clickAnswerHandler()}>Click {input}</button>
    </>
  );
}


the above code should print
input:::>>> 0 
1st click
hitting this::::>>>
input:::>>> 1 
2nd click
hitting this::>>>>
3rd click
hitting this::>>>>

and so on......
the above code is printing
input:::>>> 0
1st click
hitting this::::>>>
input:::>>> 1 
2nd click
hitting this::>>>>
input:::>>> 1 
3rd click
hitting this::>>>>

and so on......

Please, when giving an example of an output is important to have it correctly formated because it was difficult to read. I answered the issue, but is good for next questions to help other developers to correctly understand. Thanks! :)
